# Execute function on Enter

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-events

How can I execute some code when the Enter key is hit on a text field?

My approach doesn't do anything:

```
<script>
textfield.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert("abc");
    }
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="textfield">
```

PS: I don't want to use JQuery.

Comment: No it does not. The accepted answer is vanilla/plain js - it is however using 2 ways to get the event and 2 ways to get the keyCode as mandated by the browser differences when not using jQuery. That and assigning after the element is available in the DOM is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the script below the textfield so that it exists in the DOM first:

```
<input type="text" id="textfield">
<script>
textfield.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert("abc");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: or wrap in window.onload

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, that's an option as well

Comment: Also this will not work in all browsers. See linked answer for the full event handling